# To retrieve the maximum data from 2 columns based on a logic

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table where in I need to get the Maximum count. Here from below table there Packet 1 should be picked up.
The logic is as below
- It should pick up the maximum from the sum of the items in Column B and C.
- If this sum matches with another raw then it should pick the content from maximum of Column C

So in the below example it should pick packet 1.

[image]

Also I need to retrieve these 2 column values based on this selection so that I can use them for another calculation as below

Calculation = Amount Apple (Max picked up from Column C) + Mango Amount ((Max picked up from Column C)

Say for eg: Cell R1=Amount Apple, R2=Amount Mango

Original effort (not working yet):

```
=MAX(SUM(B2:C2),SUM(B3:C3),SUM(B4:C4),SUM(B5:C5))
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out any solutions here. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and explain what should have been the answer?

Comment: @Jeeped: Sorry, I am new to excel formula's. What hardly I could try was Max of each column individually. Any solution would deeply be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+MMULT(B2:C5,{1;1})+C2:C5/10^6)),A2:A5)`

Note that the part `{1;1}` represents a 2-row-by-1-column (i.e. vertical) array, and also that the separator therein (semicolon) may require amending depending upon the locale of the version of Excel being used.

Regards

Comment: Could you offer a one or two sentence explanation/reminder of what the semi-colon in `{1;1}` does for lazy-old-me and every future viewer of that elegant formula? Is it shorthand transposition of values?

Comment: @Jeeped Good point, the more so since the separator is not version-independent.

Comment: I'll let you off!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to require a formula that involves nested lookups. First, gather a set of rows (packets) that contain the maximum sum of columns B and C. From that set, determine which contains the maximum value in column C.

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(2:5)/((B2:B5+C2:C5=AGGREGATE(14, 7, (B2:B5+C2:C5), 1))*(C2:C5=AGGREGATE(14, 7, C2:C5/(B2:B5+C2:C5=AGGREGATE(14, 7, (B2:B5+C2:C5), 1)), 1))), 1))
```

If two or more contain similar maximum values in column C, this returns the first one.

[image]

Comment: thanks! what if this range is dynamic. like for the above example there are 4 packets. what if the packet goes to 100.

Comment: Given that the addition of that new criteria renders this response invalid, it would appear to be a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Please refrain from adding *'but what if ...'* addendums to your original question.

Comment: There are also plenty of examples on how to make a cyclic formula with dynamic ranges; I've written quite a few. Search for `A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1e99, A:A))`to get an idea on how to create dynamic ranges while minimizing calculation cycles.

Comment: Ha! I just googled that search phrase I provided and came up with one of my own responses as the top result. It  shows **exactly** how to accomplish what you are looking for. I hope you find it informative.